# How to separate menu and content in the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a list of menu items and content in a single page. In PC browser or ipad, I want to see both parts in the same page. But in the smaller devices such as iphone and android phone, I want to separate the two so that you selects one of menu items in a page and see its content when he clicks it.

[Jquery mobile demo page already does it](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/intro.html). But I can't figure out how I can achieve it. Can someone explain or point to any good reference? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) which illustrates how you could organize your views so that based on the client type you could provide different contents.

Comment: I was just looking for simple jquery trick. But series of the blog posts, especially [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx), surely fascinated me. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Paul, while you could definitely employ a *simple jquery trick* to hide parts of your markup on mobile phones, that would be far than optimal. You will be wasting your client's mobile phone precious bandwidth by sending markup that they are not supposed to ever see and to hide it from them on the client side. I would recommend you tackle this problem on the server.

Comment: Definitively, I see your point and I want to do it in server side. But as addressed in the last comment of [the blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx), the mobile view engine seems to have its own problems. I think I might have to wait for MVC 4.